# Scaling Scheduler Web Service

Tags: java, tomcat, scalability

We are developing an application which periodically syncs the LDAP servers of different clients with our database. This application needs to be accessed via a web portal. A web user will create, modify or delete scheduled tasks on this application. So, we have developed this application as a web service.

Now, we have to scale this application and also ensure high availability.

The application is an Axis2 based web service running on Tomcat. We have thought of httpd + mod_jk + tomcat combination for load balancing. The problem is that if a request for modification/deletion comes, then it should land on the same tomcat server on which the task was created initially. But, since, the request can come from different web users accessing web portal from different ip addresses, we can not have same session id (sticky session).

Any solutions? Different architecture? Anything.

We have also thought of using Quartz scheduler api. The site says it supports load balancing and clustering. Does anyone has experience of working on such scenario with Quartz?

Comment: It sounds like your database -- or wherever task-info is stored -- is also distributed; i.e., not a common database accessed by all web-servers. is that why you need the subsequent request to go to the original web-server?

Comment: No, all the tasks share common database.

Comment: Then, the database is the single point at which you can coordinate things. What is the reason you want subsequent requests to go to the same web-server?

Comment: If a task has been created for client A on server A, then subsequent requests for modification/deletion of that task must go to the same webserver.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is: why? After all, if all the state is stored in a database, and the database is common to all web-servers, why can't any of them handle the subsequent request. If one goes down, why can't any other pick up as if nothing happened? I guess there is some state being stored in the web-server. Anyhow, if that's what you want, I don't know how you would route it.

Comment: Storing the state in centralized database will require a polling mechanism which will check for change in state, I guess. But we have to handle some manual queries also which are not scheduled and handled immediately. And, polling mechanism will not be the right choice for real time responses.

Comment: The scenario we are handling is that a task was scheduled on server A and later on a user modified it. So, we will have to stop the task on server A first. After that it doesn't matter which server schedule the new task.

Comment: Got it. I had assumed your webserver would poll the data-store, like Quartz does. Your approach means that if a particular web-server goes down, the user has to reschedule? 

If you do not want to poll, you could broadcast a "Stop Task ABC0001" message among the Tomcats. Not saying this is the best approach, but it might be, depending on the frequency of various use-cases in your environment. If changes are infrequent, you could simply send a message like "Dirty flag: refresh all task info from database"

Comment: Yes. It looks that's the only option for us. Thanks for help @DariusX.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Quartz for your scheduling, that can be backed by a database (see JDBCJobStore). Then you could access any Tomcat server and the scheduling would be centralized. I would recommend using a key in the database that you return back to the Axis service, so that the user can reference the same data between calls.

Alternatively it is not difficult to use the database as a job scheduler, then have your tasks run on Tomcat (any location), and put the results into the database. If the results of the job (such as its status) are small, this would work fine.

Comment: I will have to do some POC for Quartz and JDBCJobStore, never worked with these.